# process running on login: can't find in AD or login batch scripts

Tags: windows-server-2003

Hallo,

I'm trying to deploy some classroom control software (NetSupport School) to some of the machines on our network but for some reason when you log off and restart the computer any user who logs on ends up re-installing the software while logging on. I spent two hours on the phone to the complanys support and we eventually nailed it down to most likely a setting in Active Directory or in the login.bat (drive mapping and settings) but we can't find anything in those that would say "run this installer at logon".

Is there anywhere else on the system that would set something like this?

Server 2003/XP.

Ta!

Answer (score 1):

Run "autoruns.exe" from SysInternals on one of the affected machines. Look for it in there.

Comment: good suggestion, nothing obvious though.

Answer (score 1):

Do GPO modeling (from the GPMC) on the user and computer that is being affected and look for GPO's that have software installs attached to them. You can also look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run to see if there is anything specified there.

There is also a Windows installer function that kicks off the remainder of an install if it is a user based install and it needed a reboot. If this is failing, it could be kicking this off everytime the user logs in since it never completes. Look in the event log to see if windows installer is creating any error events. You can use MSIZAP to kill it if it is stuck.

Comment: thanks, but it seems to be *all* the users and *all* of the computers in 3 IT suites.

Comment: then just pick one and do modeling against it to see if any GPO's have software installs attached. You can also model against the OU's that the computers and users are in.